# Web Bluetooth: Want to exclude certain devices when using navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I have an array with the names of some devices I don't want to get when I do navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice

Is there a way to keep them out the same way you can filter devices by name?

`navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [ { namePrefix: "SPDCM", }, ], optionalServices: [UUID_FOTA_SERVICE] })`

Answer (score 2):

[Chrome 114](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/ad82f97d91ebf933c754ba0da4fa81b0ee6d5b6e) has the new `"exclusionFilters"` option in `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice()` that allows web developers to exclude some devices from the browser picker. It can be used to exclude devices that match a broader filter but are unsupported.

```js
// Request access to a bluetooth device whose name starts with "Created by".
// The device named "Created by Francois" has been reported as unsupported.
const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{ namePrefix: "Created by" }],
  exclusionFilters: [{ name: "Created by Francois" }],
});
```

You can play with it at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/exclusion-filters.html

Resources:

- https://developer.chrome.com/articles/bluetooth/#exclusion-filters
- https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#ref-for-dom-requestdeviceoptions-exclusionfilters
- https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/pull/600

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to exclude some devices as of March 2023.
The requestDevice filters ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/requestDevice) & [specification](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-requestdevice) [examples](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#example-filter-by-services)) only select criteria to include, but not mask, items to be included.

I've started a [specification issue requesting exclusion filters](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/599).  Please review and comment there to make a proposal.  Adding as many specifics about your use case (e.g. specific device examples) will help motivate the work.